# looping over multidimensional array of elements?

Tags: jquery

I got a bunch of input fields like this:

```
<input type="text" class="amount" data-type="amount[aquisition][000014]" value="16.20">
<input type="text" class="amount" data-type="amount[aquisition][000014]" value="11.60">

<input type="text" class="amount" data-type="amount[aquisition][000345]" value="9.10">
<input type="text" class="amount" data-type="amount[aquisition][000345]" value="5.40">
```

I want to add up the values of the elements wich have [aquisition] and the following number that is unknown but where there are several of in the same document.

Tried to work with `each();` but it wont work when theres more then one bracket. I am also able to modify the way the HTML input fields are generated.

```
$('[data-type="amount[aquisition]"]').each(function(){
        console.log($(this));
    });
```

I would expect the above to loop over all elements with amount[aquisition] and return arrays for each unique second set of brackets. But nothing happens, not even an error.

Any ideas?

Thx!

Comment: `Tried to work with each();`: why don't you share that code?

Comment: Yep can you post what you've already tried, it can be a matter of chars escaping `:/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a partial attribute selector:

```
// match data-type values beginning with "amount[aquisition]"
$('[data-type^="amount[aquisition]"]').each(function(){ ... });


// match data-type values containing "amount[aquisition]"
$('[data-type*="amount[aquisition]"]').each(function(){ ... });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/76tvB/1

You'd then use some string parsing to grab the value from the second set of brackets.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/76tvB/4

```
var myNums = [];

// match data-type values beginning with "amount[aquisition]"
$('[data-type^="amount[aquisition]"]').each(function () {
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
    var myNum = $(this).attr('data-type');
    myNum = myNum.replace('amount[aquisition][', '').replace(']', '');
    myNums.push(myNum);

    $('#dropbox').text( myNums );
});
```

You'll have to do a check against the array to filter duplicates.

Comment: Updated second fiddle to use an actual array.

Comment: This did the trick, thank you very much! I did not know about partial attribute selectors yet.